# How to use dplyr to find unique entries in the previous rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a really long dataframe, with more or less the following structure:

```
df <- data.frame(
dates = c("2011-10-01","2011-10-01","2011-10-01","2011-10-02","2011-10-03","2011-10-05","2011-10-06","2011-10-06"),
ids = c("A","A","B","C","D","A","E","D"),
values = c(10,1,25,2,5,10,4,1))

> df
       dates ids values
1 2011-10-01   A     10
2 2011-10-01   A      1
3 2011-10-01   B     25
4 2011-10-02   C      2
5 2011-10-03   D      5
6 2011-10-05   A     10
7 2011-10-06   E      4
8 2011-10-06   D      1
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
       dates   unique_ids sum_values
1 2011-10-01            2         36
2 2011-10-02            3         38
3 2011-10-03            4         43
4 2011-10-04            4         43
5 2011-10-05            4         53
6 2011-10-06            5         58
```

i.e. for each date unique_ids gives the number of unique ids corresponding to earlier dates and sum_values gives the sum of values corresponding to earlier dates.

I definitely want to avoid for cycles because the original df too big. So I was thinking to use dplyr.

I know how to obtain the sum_value

```
df %>%
group_by(dates) %>%
summarize(sum_values_daily = sum(values)) %>%
mutate(sum_values = cumsum(sum_values_daily)) %>%
select(dates, sum_values)
```

I don't know how to obtains the unique_ids column.

Any Idea?

Comment: `df %>%  group_by(dates) %>%  summarise(unique_ids = n_distinct(ids), 
            sum_values = sum(values))`

Comment: Hi Ronak, what you suggest is not the desired result,
I want as uniques_ids for a certain date the number of unique ids of all the previous dates, as well the sum of the values corresponding to the previous dates.

Comment: please double check your expected output, i dont think its correct.

Comment: mtoto I  think it is correct but not clearly explained. The unique # of id is 2 and separately, the sum of all values for 2011-10-01 is 36, but you are not only adding the the values for the unique id #s.

Comment: @mtoto the desired output is correct. I do not want a simply df %>% group_by(date) %>% summarize(unique_ids=n_distinct(ids),  sum_values = sum(values))

Comment: There should be one row for `2011-10-05` as we group by date.

Comment: Right sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to calculate the number of distinct `ids` *across groups*, first we'll need to define a boolean column that will allow us to sum only the *unique* values.

Secondly, you want to include missing dates from your original `df` in your expected output, so we'll also need to perform a `right_join` with the full sequence of dates. I assume here that your `dates` column is already of class `Date`. This will produce `NA` values that we `replace` by `0`.

Finally we calculate the `cumsum` for both `unique_ids` and `sum_values`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(unique_ids = !duplicated(ids)) %>%
        group_by(dates) %>%
        summarise(unique_ids = sum(unique_ids),
                  sum_values = sum(values)) %>%
        right_join(data.frame(dates = seq(min(df$date), 
                                          max(df$dates), 
                                          by = 1))) %>%
        mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)), -dates)  %>%
        mutate_each(funs(cumsum), -dates)
#       dates unique_ids sum_values
#      <date>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 2011-10-01          2         36
#2 2011-10-02          3         38
#3 2011-10-03          4         43
#4 2011-10-04          4         43
#5 2011-10-05          4         53
#6 2011-10-06          5         58
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, Here is a `data.table` solution. For clarity, I'll present a three line version, though these lines could be chained into a single line.

```
library(data.table)
# convert to data.table and make dates a Data data type
setDT(df)[, "dates" := as.Date(dates)]
# merge on the daily values (missing 10-04 in original data)
# convert NAs to 0 for missing dates, calculate cumulative sums of unique ID and values
df <- df[.(seq.Date(min(dates), max(dates), by="day")), on="dates",
         .(dates, values=cumsum(ifelse(is.na(values), 0, values)),
           unique_ids=cumsum(!duplicated(ids) & !is.na(ids)))]
# aggregate by date, saving the max of unique ID and value
df <- df[, .(unique_ids=max(unique_ids), sum_values=max(values)), by=dates]
```

This returns

```
df 
        dates unique_ids sum_values
1: 2011-10-01          2         36
2: 2011-10-02          3         38
3: 2011-10-03          4         43
4: 2011-10-04          4         43
5: 2011-10-05          4         53
6: 2011-10-06          5         58
```

Comment: @mtoto Thanks for catching the other NA... On your second point, you are partially correct. When using `:=` for example, as in `setDT(df)[, "dates" := as.Date(dates)]` above, data.table assigns by reference. However, in most other operations, it makes a copy (another exception is `set`). To see this, try the first two lines of my code, without the `df <-` in the second line. then print `df` in the console. You will notice that 10-04 is missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    mutate(dates = as.Date(dates), ids = as.character(ids)) %>% 
    group_by(dates) %>%
    summarise(ids = list(unique(ids)), values = sum(values)) %>%
    merge(data.frame(dates = seq.Date(min(.$dates), max(.$dates), "day")), all.y = TRUE) %>% 
    transmute(
        dates,
        uniqe_ids = map_int(accumulate(ids, ~unique(c(.x, .y))), length),
        sum_values = accumulate(values, ~sum(.x, .y, na.rm = TRUE))
    )
```

The first part, `mutate`, `group_by` and then `summarise` I guess, is easy to understand: some preparations, than we collect unique ids and sum values within each day. The result is:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
       dates       ids values
      <date>    <list>  <dbl>
1 2011-10-01 <chr [2]>     36
2 2011-10-02 <chr [1]>      2
3 2011-10-03 <chr [1]>      5
4 2011-10-05 <chr [1]>     10
5 2011-10-06 <chr [2]>      5
```

Then we merge this with `data.frame(dates = seq.Date(min(.$dates), max(.$dates), "day"))` to fill in possible date gaps.

Now we need to sort of walk from up to down cumulatively on `ids` and `values` variables. 
For `ids` we firstly use `purrr::accumulate` with `~unique(c(.x, .y))` function. This means that we start with the first cell of `ids` and then concatenate it (`c`) step-by-step with the following cells keeping the unique values only. So in our case this would evaluate to:

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

[[5]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

But we need to know just the number of distinct ids so we map then `length` function on it with the help of `purrr::map_int`.

For `sum_values` we calculate the cumulative sum (we can't use `cumsum` because we may have NAs after the merging).